# How can I retrieve session value in login handler that I have set in successhandler

Tags: java, session, spring-security

I have set a session attribute in LoginSuccessHandler(extending CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler) like

```
public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication)
            throws IOException, ServletException {


HttpSession session = request.getSession();
session.setAttribute("TICKET", "dummyVAL");

}
```

I want to retrieve the same value in LogoutSuccessHandler(extending SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler).But when I do

```
public void onLogoutSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {

HttpSession session = request.getSession();
session.getAttribute("TICKET");
    }
```

**I get null.How can I retrieve session value in login handler that I have set in successhandler.**

Comment: r u using spring security

Comment: Yes I am using Spring Security

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after session invalidation spring-security will call `logout-success-url` so you will not find session here

so work around is  `call a logout url pattern from logout link`
and use this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/logout", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String logout(ModelMap model, HttpSession session) {
    //** do some thing **//
    return "redirect:/j_spring_security_logout";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think "onLogutSuccess" method will be fired when your session gets destroyed. thus no value or parameter can be found in session.
And what you are doing with request.getSession() is that you are creating a new session which in turn returns null for the attribute as it does not exists for that session.